# Why are ("non-parametric") Gaussian Processes a good fit for Bayesian Optimization

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

I understand why Gaussian Processes [are considered "non-parametric"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46588/why-are-gaussian-process-models-called-non-parametric), but why do most authors use non-parametric models for Bayesian Optimization?

What's the benefit of using such models as opposed to parametric approaches? (GLM, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parametric models assume the samples are from a specific distribution e.g.  from a mixture of Gaussians where the number of Gaussian components is known a priori.  This is restrictive since for most real-word problems we cannot know beforehand how complex the data is.  For example, a nonparametric method should find the number of Gaussian components itself.   As you see in my example, the nonparametric method still assumes something, that the data is from a mixture of Gaussians.   But does not assume the number of components.  Gaussian processes are nonparametric too.  It uses every single training point to build a basis.  So GP methods are flexible and powerful. They can learn complicated distributions (or decision boundaries in case of Gaussian process classification).

Answer (score 0):

There's no any evidence why objective function should be linear, so nonparametrics like gaussian processes, random forests or neural networks are used as surrogates to approximate it as nonlinear function.

Comment: you may say, let's use parametric models like n-degree polynomials or splines, but Gaussian Processes can be considered as generalization of them

Comment: Yes but could not one argue that there is no evidence, either, that an objective function would fit any *other* model? I.e. all models are equally likely to be a good fit in the absence of data, unless you know _something_ about the objective function?